# Qt Unit tests - show only failed ones

Tags: qt

Is it possible that Qt only outputs the Unit Tests that have failed?

Right now I get a huge list that 140 have been passed and 3 have failed. I would like to only see the ones that have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-silent` command line option. It only shows fatal errors, test failures and minimal status messages.